# django It seems the view func do not work

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to write a FBV to delete a subject, but there are some problem I can't figure out. It's Django 1.7.1. Below are related codes.

The model Communication:

```
...
@models.permalink
def get_delete_url(self):
    return 'comm_delete', [self.uuid]
```

the URLconf:

```
url(r'^(?P<uuid>[\w-]+)/delete/$', views.comm_delete, name='comm_delete'),
```

the views:

```
def comm_delete(request, uuid):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Communication, uuid=uuid)
    account = Account.objects.get(id=obj.account.id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        obj.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('crmapp.accounts.views.account_detail', args=(account.uuid,)))
    return render(request, 'subject_confirm_delete.html', {'object_name': 'Communication', 'object': obj})
```

when I click

```
<a class="cancel" href="{{ comm.get_delete_url }}"></a>
```

the page move to uuid/delete/ url, the form display Communication object. If I still click the cancel button, just refresh the page and nothing changed.
So how can I fix it? Help me please!

The object_confirm_delete.html:
[image: object_confirm_delete.html]

the page when clicked cancel button:
[image: clicked_move_to_page]

the urls.py in app Communications like this:

```
url(r'^(?P<uuid>[\w-]+)/', views.comm_detail, name='comm_detail'), 
url(r'^(?P<uuid>[\w-]+)/delete/$', views.comm_delete, name='comm_delete'),
```

as you can see, the first one has no '$' at the end, so when I link the url of second one, the first one's regex matched and perform the view comm_detail. After I modify it, It execute well.

Comment: I don't understand what else you are expecting to happen when you click that link.

Comment: Please post your `subject_confirm_delete.html`.

Comment: @Selcuk Updated, Thanks

Comment: @Daniel Roseman, Help!!!

Comment: I can't help because I still don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: please post your code as text not as a picture.

Comment: Trying to understand your question. So when you click `Cancel` on the confirmation page, the browser isn't going back to the previous page? Is that the problem? Do you have JavaScript enabled in your browser? A suggestion: I'd use a server-rendered link for the cancel button, not JavaScript, just in case a client has disabled it, it would needlessly break functionality for them.

Comment: @Selcuk There is another urlconf take the url first, so then move to the template which it point to. The logic is correct.

Comment: @C14L Thanks, I've found the problem out.

Comment: @Charles Good. Please post the solution, so others may find it in the future. Or, if that makes more sense, delete the question, so it will not stay open as "no answer".

Comment: @C14L I post the mistake I've made on the question text. Sorry, I don't know I can answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

the urls.py in app Communications like this:

```
url(r'^(?P<uuid>[\w-]+)/', views.comm_detail, name='comm_detail'), 
url(r'^(?P<uuid>[\w-]+)/delete/$', views.comm_delete, name='comm_delete'),
```

as you can see, the first one has no '$' at the end, so when I link the url of second one, the first one's regex matched and perform the view comm_detail. After I modify it, It execute well. It means the FBV is correct.